# Does scheduled task receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION message?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have a program that reacts to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` to perform some cleanup running as a scheduled task. Logging indicates that the cleanup code is not executed. Do applications running as a scheduled task receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages or is there any other way to detect Window shutdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The messages are sent to top level windows. If your process has one, it will be sent the message. If you don't have one, then you can create one for that purpose. If your application is a console application then `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` is the recommended way to receive such notification.

It transpires, from the comment thread, that your process is running under the `SYSTEM` account. According to the [`documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686227.aspx), this means that it will not be shutdown by the system.

> Applications running in the system security context do not get shut down by the operating system. They get notified of shutdown or logoff through the callback function installable via SetConsoleCtrlHandler.

Comment: So you are saying that everything that runs as a scheduled task still receives the messages?

Comment: From the perspective of the system, a process started as a scheduled task isn't special. It's just another process. If it has top level windows then they'll be sent the message.

Comment: @jpfollenius - However the task scheduler has the capability to run an application on a non interactive desktop for instance. The Q&A game... Does your task ....?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz in my tests, I used the SYSTEM account. So processes running on non-interactive desktops do not receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION?

Comment: Why are you using SYSTEM? Do you have a top level window? Which session and which desktop is your process running on? Do you know that?

Comment: @jpfollenius - That is correct. See remarks in [SetProcessShutdownParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686227(v=vs.85).aspx) for instance. Use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.